# Importing partial data into MySQL from CSV

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a CSV that is a **partial projection** of an origin table. I have the same table structure in my DB.

I would like to import only those columns into my DB, given that no additional `NOT NULL` constraints are in place (I explicitly disabled some of them). I don't know how to import them.

I have tried the following: from MySQL Workbench, right click on table and then `Edit table data`, then on the screen I tried the "Import records from an external file" button, loaded the CSV file but I got the following error:

```
[Window Title]
MySQL Workbench

[Main Instruction]
Error importing recordset

[Content]
error calling Python module function SQLIDEUtils.importRecordsetDataFromFile

[OK]
```

The column names are the same as in the DB but these are partial (not all columns as DB). The table is currently empty.

What can I do to import the data into MySQL?

Comment: I have the same problem. I actually exported the file from MySQL Workbench, did some editors and tried to reimport it. No idea why its not working. I'm using the Mac version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that is the error that tool gives for ANY problems importing CSV data.  They have opened a bug for more descriptive error responses.

For me it turned out that it can not work with non-Windows line breaks.  So if your file came from Unix/Linux or Mac it will not work.  You can just open it in Excel though and re-save it as an MS-DOS CSV and then it works.  Other things that can make it throw up are any use of ";".

Also the tool has NO column mapping options so you have to have your import file matched to the table setup perfectly.  If you have columns mis-matched or data types mis-matched it will also throw-up.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same question and error when I was importing a csv file into MAC Mysqlworkbench.

I restored my file as windows comma separated (`.csv`). This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check do you have permissions to import (on insert), and if you import clearing old data check do you have permissions on delete.
2. If it won't help, create a new table with least restrictions which has absolutely identical columns as in CSV file, try to import to it. If ok - just update/insert into your target table
3. If it won't help, try to import on another database.
4. If it won't help, check CSV file - is all contents is ok? (may be it should try first)

Comment: I was importing as root. I don't think I had permission problems